# Partition of $\mathbb{R}^+$ into two semigroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory, semigroups

> Can the semigroup  $(\mathbb R^+ ,+)$ be partitioned into two semigroups?

I have been trying but haven't found anything, please help.

Comment: all the finite $\cup $ $+ \infty$

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth: Sorry but I don't regard $\infty$ an element of $\mathbb R^+$ , it is an element of extended reals

Comment: Are you asking if you can partition $\Bbb R^+$ into two sets which are closed under addition? I'm fairly sure that I posted at least one such answer. [And here it is!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244456/using-zorns-lemma-show-that-mathbb-r-is-the-disjoint-union-of-two-sets-clo/244468#244468)

Comment: We have all these non-constructive answers.  When you finish with those, show that it cannot be done where the two subgroups are Lebesgue measurable sets.

Comment: I will point out that the solution can be also found in Komjath, Totik: Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory, [p.310](https://books.google.com/books?id=rbCmt-2NxtIC&pg=PA310). The solution uses Zorn Lemma and is similar to Yiorgos S. Smyrlis' answer. Minor difference is that they work with pairs of sets closed under addition and *multiplication by positive rationals*. This simplifies the reasoning that the maximal element has the required properties a bit. (And it is easy to see that a set with required properties must be closed under $\mathbb Q^+$-multiples.)

Answer (score 4):

**The Solution:** Notice that $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Choose some linear function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ over this vector space for which there exist an $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f(x)\geq 0$ and $f(y)<0$. Then, the sets $A=\{x:f(x)\geq 0\}$ and $B=\{x:f(x)<0\}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ partition the space and are semigroups.

**Some notes on it:** The existence of such an $f$ is guaranteed by the axiom of choice, which is equivalent to the statement that all vector spaces have a basis. Once we have a basis $S$, we can change to the basis $S'=\{|s|:s\in S\}$ and define $f$ on $S'$ such that it takes a negative value for at least one $s\in S'$ and takes a non-negative value for some other $s\in S'$.

A more general statement we could make is that we could partition $\mathbb{R}^+$ into as many subsemigroups as we want by choosing more linear functions - for instance, if we had a $f$ and $g$ so that none of the following were empty, we could partition into three sets as:
$$\{x:f(x)\geq 0\}$$
$$\{x:f(x)< 0\wedge g(x)\geq 0\}$$
$$\{x:f(x)< 0\wedge g(x) < 0\}$$
(We could also partition into the sets for which a single $f$ is positive, negative, or zero, but this doesn't generalize well)

Another note is that $f$ could be $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ not $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ - I used the latter to emphasize that I want $f$ to be linear *in the rationals* - that $f(kx)=kf(x)$ is only necessary when $k$ is rational.

Comment: You can make a $\mathbb Q$-basis of $\mathbb R$ starting from $\{1,\sqrt 2\}$. Then define $f(1)=7$ and $f(\sqrt 2)=-100$.

Comment: Very nice proof. When I saw the claim, I thought that Hamel basis might be useful to show this. But I was not able to come up with this elegant idea.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is YES.

We shall follow the idea which appeared [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244456/using-zorns-lemma-show-that-mathbb-r-is-the-disjoint-union-of-two-sets-clo/244468#244468), and I will explain the final step in detail.

Let $$\mathscr F=\{(S,T)\,:\,S,T\subset \mathbb R^+,\,S\cap T=\varnothing\,\,\& \,\,S,T\,\,\text{semigroups}\}.$$ Then $\mathscr F\ne\varnothing$, as $\,\big(\mathbb Q^+,\sqrt{2}\,\mathbb Q^+\big)\in\mathscr F$, and  if we define "$\preceq$" in $\mathscr F$ as
$$
(S_1,T_1)\,\preceq\,(S_2,T_2),
$$
if and only if $S_1\subset S_2$ and $T_1\subset T_2$, then clearly "$\preceq$" is a partial ordering.

We shall use [Zorn's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn's_lemma) to obtain a maximal element $(S_{\mathrm{max}},T_{\mathrm{max}})\in\mathscr F$, i.e., an element not possessing a strictly larger, in the $\preceq$-sense, and show that 
$S_{\mathrm{max}} \cup T_{\mathrm{max}}=\mathbb R^+$.

In order to apply Zorn's Lemma and extract this maximal element, we need to establish that every *chain* has an *upper bound*. A chain $\mathscr C$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathscr F$, which is totally ordered by $\preceq$, i.e., if $(S_1,T_1),\,(S_2,T_2)\in\mathscr C$, then either
$(S_1,T_1)\,\preceq\,(S_2,T_2)$ or $(S_2,T_2)\,\preceq\,(S_1,T_1)$. Upper bound of $\mathscr C$ is an element $(S,T)\in\mathscr F$, larger than all the elements of $\mathscr C$, i.e., $(S',T')\preceq (S,T)$, for all $\,(S',T')\in \mathscr C$. If we set
$$
\hat S=\bigcup\{S: (S,T)\in \mathscr C,\,\,\text{for some semigroup}\,\,T\subset\mathbb R^+ \}, \\
\hat T=\bigcup\{T: (S,T)\in \mathscr C,\,\,\text{for some semigroup}\,\,S\subset\mathbb R^+ \},
$$
we shall show that $(\hat S,\hat T)\in\mathscr F$. Indeed, if $x,y\in \hat S$, then $x\in S_1$ and $y\in S_2$, for some $(S_1,T_1),(S_2,T_2)\in\mathscr C$. But as $\mathscr C$ is a chain, then  either $S_1\subset S_2$ or $S_2\subset S_1$. Say the first happens, then $x,y\in S_2$, and as $S_2$ is a semigroup, then $x+y\in S_2\subset \hat S$. Similarly, if $S_2\subset S_1$, and similarly $\hat T$ is a semigroup. Also, $\hat S\cap\hat T=\varnothing$, for if $x\in \hat S\cap\hat T$, then $x\in S_1$, for some $(S_1,T_1)\in\mathscr C$ and
$x\in T_2$, for some $(S_2,T_2)\in\mathscr C$, and as  $\mathscr C$ is a chain, assuming for example that $(S_1,T_1)\preceq(S_2,T_2)$, we obtain that $x\in S_2\cap T_2$, which is a contradiction, as $S_2,T_2$ are assumed disjoint. Also, $(\hat S,\hat T)$ is an upper bound of $\mathscr C$, as by its definition $S\subset \hat S$ and $T\subset\hat T$, for all $(S,T)\in\mathscr C$.

Hence, every chain in $\mathscr C$ has an upper bound and thus Zorn's Lemma is applicable, which means that $\mathscr F$ possesses a maximal element $(S_{\mathrm{max}},T_{\mathrm{max}})$. As $S_{\mathrm{max}},T_{\mathrm{max}}\subset\mathbb R^+$ are two disjoint semigroups, it only remains to show that 
$S_{\mathrm{max}} \cup T_{\mathrm{max}}=\mathbb R^+$.

Suppose not, and that $z\in \mathbb R^+\smallsetminus(S_{\mathrm{max}} \cup T_{\mathrm{max}})$ and let $S'$ be the semigroup generated by $\hat S\cup\{z\}$ and $T'$
the semigroup generated by $\hat T\cup\{z\}$.
We shall obtain a contradiction by showing that 
either $(S',\hat T)\in\mathscr F$ or $(\hat S,T')\in\mathscr F$, each of which is strictly larger (with respect to $\preceq$) than the maximal element $(\hat S,\hat T)$.

The elements of $S'$ are of the form $x+nz$, where $x\in \hat S$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, and similarly the elements of $T'$ are of the form $y+mz$, where $y\in \hat T$and $m\in\mathbb N$. If $S'\cap \hat T\ne\varnothing$, then 
$$
x+nz=y, \quad\text{for some $x\in\hat S,\,y\in\hat T,\,n\in\mathbb N$}, \tag{1}
$$
and if 
$\hat S\cap T'\ne\varnothing$, then 
$$
x'=y'+n'z, \quad\text{for some $x'\in\hat S,\,y'\in\hat T,\,n'\in\mathbb N$}. \tag{2}
$$
Now $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that
$$
nn'z=n'y-n'x=nx'-ny',
$$
and hence $nx'+n'x=ny'+n'y\in \hat S\cap \hat T$, which is not possible. Thus, either $S'\cap \hat T=\varnothing$ or $\hat S\cap T'=\varnothing$, which implies that
$(\hat S,T')\in\mathscr F$ or $(S',\hat T)\in \mathscr F$, which contradicts the fact that $(\hat S,\hat T)$ is maximal.

Thus $\hat S\cup\hat T=\mathbb R^+$ and we are done.

**Note.** Although I find Meelo's answer extremely elegant, I believe that this answer has certain advantages:

a. Using the same argument we can partition $\mathbb R^+$ in $k$ semigroups, for every $k\in\mathbb N$.

b. This method works for other commutative groups, $G$, possessing a subset $T$, which is a semigroup and $G=T\cup\{0\}\cup (-T)$.

Comment: A semigroup $\{2,3,\ldots\}$ does not become a group after adding $\{0,-2,-3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: In the new edition, it is not clear whether $c_1+d_1$ belongs to $S$ or $T$.

Comment: I have made a correction.

Comment: I still think that $c_1+d_1$ is neither in $S$ nor in $T$.

Comment: @SouvikDey: I am now providing a totally new answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $H=\{h_i:i\in I\}$ be a Hamel basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$, where the index set $I$ is well-ordered. Thus each real number $x$ has a unique expression as a finite linear combination of elements of $H$ with rational coefficients, i.e., $x=\sum_{i\in I}x_ih_i$ where $x_i\in\mathbb Q$ and $\{i\in I:x_i\ne0\}$ is finite. If $x\ne0$, define $f(x)$ to be the **first** nonzero coefficient in this expression, i.e., $f(x)=x_i\ne0$, and $x_j=0$ for all $j\lt i$.

Let$$A=\{x\in\mathbb R^+:f(x)\gt0\}$$and let$$B=\{x\in\mathbb R^+:f(x)\lt0\}.$$

It is easy to see that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint nonempty sets whose union is $\mathbb R^+$, and that each is closed under addition.

Comment: Very nice! I hadn't seen a proof via Hamel basis.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **yes**. Below is a proof that there are sub-semigroups $\overline{S},\overline{T}$ of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ such that $\overline{S}\cap \overline{T}=\{0\}$ and $\overline{S}\cup \overline{T}=\mathbb{R}$.

Assume that semigroups $S_1,T_1\subset\mathbb{R}$

(1) are closed under multiplying by non-negative rationals (that is, $S=S\mathbb{Q}_+$ and $T=T\mathbb{Q}_+$);

(2) satisfy $S\cap T=\{0\}$, $S-T\subset S$, and $T-S\subset T$.

If $\alpha\notin S_1\cup T_1$, then semigroups $S'=S+\alpha\mathbb{Q}_+$ and $T'=T-\alpha\mathbb{Q}_+$ satisfy (1) and (2) and contain $\alpha$ in their union. A standard application of Zorn's lemma completes the proof.

Comment: @user26857 Note that $S\cap\mathbb{R}_+$ is a semigroup as well.

Comment: Right! But maybe you should have written this explicitly. (Btw, you also have to avoid as their intersection be $\{0\}$ in order to find a partition.)

Comment: @user26857 I don't know, maybe the OP means that $\mathbb{R}^+$ is the set of positive reals. Anyway, we do not need to care about zero, because if $S$ is a sub-semigroup of $\mathbb{R}_+$ then $S\setminus\{0\}$ is a sub-semigroup of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and vice versa.