# Can the real numbers be partitioned into two sets which are both closed under multiplication?

Tags: real-numbers, set-partition

Except for the trivial case of the partition consisting of the real number $0$ and everything else, is there any other partition of the entire set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ into two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ and $B$ are both closed under multiplication?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: There is a pretty basic example...

Comment: Think of the magnitude of the products.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Which one? OP already discarded $\{\{0\}, \mathbb{R}^*\}$.

Comment: @BrunoB I'm trying not to answer the question with so little work, but there is an another example. (Well, a couple, but all related.)

Comment: I see, thanks for the heads up, and sorry for bothering you. (And yeah, just thought of an example as well)

Comment: Oh, I just thought of the interval $[-1,1]$ and its complement.

Comment: Are there instances when neither A nor B is an interval?

Comment: @SpectreDNZ I feel like that would be an interesting question. Something that I linked earlier (and that I'll link right now) about the positive numbers might serve, but it would be probably advisable to make it another question altogether. Also note that one of the main links provided there has died it seems, at least on my end. The post in question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2285600/1104384